# Net::SFTP::Foreign new failed with transport

Tags: windows, perl, sftp

When I use transport API of Net::SFTP::Foreign to connect to remote server on windows, It reports error

> "Invalid option 'host' or bad combination of options" after
>   Net::SFTP::Foreign->new is invoked

code is below:

```
pipe $pR,$pW;
  $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new("$user\@$ip",transport=>[$pR,$pW]) or 
  $rdyTCE{$city1} = 1;
```

Comment: plink method can work now. but transport still cannot work after more tries

Answer (score 0):

According to module documentation available on CPAN: http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-SFTP-Foreign-1.81/lib/Net/SFTP/Foreign.pm#API

```
transport => [$in_fh, $out_fh, $pid]
allows one to use an already open pipe or socket as the transport for the SFTP protocol.
```

So you don't need host. Pipes will be used.

Comment: But how can I open pipe to the remote SFTP host? can you show me some code about this? thanks in advance

Comment: Never used it before. The point is that you should use connection information to make module connect to host, or pipes if you did it yourself. no sense to use them both.

Comment: I am still confused. An example should be better. What I care is: when there are no plink can be invoked, how can I connect to remote SFTP server using Net-SFTP-Foreign. From the  module documentation available on CPAN, transport can be used. but I don't know how to use it.